# Activity with "android.intent.action.SEND" intent filter is not showing up in list when sharing photo from stock Google Photos app

Tags: android

I have an Android app with an activity with an intent filter set to receive photos and videos. It is declared in my AndroidManifest.xml as so:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.foo.gallery.app.activity.RecievePhotosActivity"
    android:label="@string/photoapp_gallery_common_app_name"
    android:exported="true"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >

    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

However, when going into the stock Lollipop Photos app and sharing a photo, my app does not appear in the list.

My app does appear in the share list when sharing from other apps, like OneDrive, Dropbox, and Quickpic. The stock Photos app is the only one I've found so far where my app doesn't show up.

Comment: Try android.intent.action.View

Comment: Tried and didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. My app was named "Photos" - the same as the stock Photos app. I guess Google decided to hide apps with the same name in the share list.